# Not able to update column in DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update a column in one table with values in another column which is another table. I have to update around 100000 records (not a single row update).

My query is

```
update asset_dmr_revision adr 
   set adr.revision_date = (select adrt.revision_date_test 
                              from asset_dmr_revision_test adrt,
                                   asset_dmr_revision ad 
                             where ad.id = adrt.id 
                               and adrt.revision_date_test is not null
                               and ad.asset_id = adrt.asset_id)
```

But when I run in toad it says "single-row subquery returns more than one row" . How to update all coumns ? I am using oracle

Comment: mysql or oracle ? make up your mind :)

Comment: Your subquery returns more than 1 row that's why you getting error

Comment: I don't see anything in your subquery that correlates it to the table you're updating.  Unless your query returns a single row, which seems unlikely, I would expect that you would want some sort of condition that relates the `asset_dmr_revision` table in the `update` statement to one of the tables in the subquery.  Perhaps you just want to omit the reference to `asset_dmr_revision` in the subquery and to use the outer table instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `and rownum = 1` or `and rownum <=1` to the inner select query. This will ensure that always only 1 record is returned by the inner query.

```
select adrt.revision_date_test 
                             from asset_dmr_revision_test adrt,
                                   asset_dmr_revision ad 
                             where ad.id = adrt.id 
                               and adrt.revision_date_test is not null
                               and ad.asset_id = adrt.asset_id
                               and rownum <= 1
```

Note: In my opinion, `rownum <=1` is known to provide better performance than `rownum=1`

EDIT:

Try below update query:

```
update asset_dmr_revision adr 
   set adr.revision_date = nvl(select adrt.revision_date_test 
                              from asset_dmr_revision_test adrt,
                              asset_dmr_revision ad 
                               where ad.id = adrt.id 
                               and adrt.revision_date_test is not null
                               and ad.asset_id = adrt.asset_id
                   and adr.id = adrt.id
                   and rownum <=1
                   ) , adr.revision_date);
```

Basically, there is no correlation between the outer adr table and the inner adrt table. So i have added additional condition `and adr.id = adrt.id`. Check and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I added that but it is updating all the records with only one data

Comment: Though there is null check on adrt.revision_date_test it is saying "ORA-01407: cannot update ("DTV_B2B2"."ASSET_DMR_REVISION"."REVISION_DATE") to NULL"

Comment: @SanjayMalhotra: Refer my edit. I have added a null value check in the inner select query. If the value from inner query is null, then the existing date itself will be updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57728/discussion-between-nishanthi-grashia-and-sanjay-malhotra).

Comment: Missing expression. I removed the brace at the end but still it says the same. Syntax is proper only.

Answer (score 1):

The inner select:

```
select adrt.revision_date_test 
from asset_dmr_revision_test adrt, asset_dmr_revision ad 
where ad.id = adrt.id 
and adrt.revision_date_test is not null
and ad.asset_id = adrt.asset_id
```

returns more than one row - so the DB gets "confused" and doesn't know which one to pick...

Comment: @SanjayMalhotra there is no "work around" - you should write a more specific query that'll return only a single record.

Comment: I am not getting idea how to update it. I tried using asset_dmr_revision_test object outside but then it says missing set keyword

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, you need to return only ONE row.
You can achieve this by using functions :

```
update asset_dmr_revision adr 
   set adr.revision_date = (select max(adrt.revision_date_test) 
                              from asset_dmr_revision_test adrt,
                                   asset_dmr_revision ad 
                             where ad.id = adr.id 
                               and adrt.revision_date_test is not null
                               and ad.asset_id = adrt.asset_id
                               group by ad.id)
```

Replace MAX with the functionally correct function in your case.

Also, if the value is NULL you might need to assign a default value :

```
update asset_dmr_revision adr 
   set adr.revision_date = nvl((select max(adrt.revision_date_test) 
                              from asset_dmr_revision_test adrt,
                                   asset_dmr_revision ad 
                             where ad.id = adr.id 
                               and adrt.revision_date_test is not null
                               and ad.asset_id = adrt.asset_id
                               group by ad.id),adr.revision_date_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to update each row that matches the sub-query. To do that, I would recommend using `merge`:

```
MERGE INTO asset_dmr_revision adr
USING      (SELECT adrt.id, adrt.revision_date_test
            FROM   asset_dmr_revision_test adrt
                   JOIN asset_dmr_revision ad
                      ON ad.id = adrt.id AND adrt.asset_id = ad.asset_id
            WHERE  adrt.revision_date_test IS NOT NULL) a
ON         (adr.id = s.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET revision_date = s.revision_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a procedure which resolved the problem. Thanks a lot Alfsin and Nishanthi for the support..:)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure DTV_B2B2.update_revision_date is 

cursor revDate  is (select revision_date_test,id from asset_dmr_revision_test);

begin
--DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('outside loop');
for rec in revDate 
loop
update asset_dmr_revision adr set adr.revision_date = rec.revision_date_test
where adr.id = rec.id;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an SQL solution, only a work around, that will be very inefficient. Like other contributors said, you need to make your sub Select return only one row, either by using ROWNUM or preferably by using a GROUPING function (max, min, sum etc...) that will always return ONE and only ONE row